# CQRS/Event sourcing project structure

Tags: visual-studio, architecture, cqrs, event-sourcing

I have my first CQRS project which uses event sourcing and I was wondering if this type of project should be structured in a different way in Visual studio compared to other projects that involve multiple tiers?

For example, in the pastt projects created had layers such as Remoting, App services, domain etc and it was clear each layer/assembly touched the one below it. These assemblies seemed to do a lot and using a tool like NDepend did say much about the structure of the project.

However, with a CQRS project would it be better just to have smaller assemblies that show their intent i.e. assembly for commands, another for events, another for event handlers etc.

Now with NDepend it would give me a better representation how the assemblies are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I generally structure my CQRS projects with smaller projects that are descriptive of their intent -- Command, Domain, Event, Denormalizer, Repository, Command Service, etc.

It makes it much easier to navigate through your solution this way, and also makes it easier for others on your team (or new team members coming on board) to work with the various components of your system.

Also, if you have a team working on this, you can easily let one group focus primarily on the domain project (probably your higher-end team members) while your junior members could work on the denormalizer project.

You'll end up with (probably) more projects, but they'll be smaller chunks and much easier to understand their purpose.  Kind of like the Single Responsibility Principle, but at the project level.

Hope this helps.  Good luck.

Comment: No problem - glad I could be of help.  Good luck!